# How to create a folder getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin

How to create a folder  getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated I use minimum APi level  21  and Android Studio 3.4.2
[my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMiH7.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMiH7.png

Answer (score 0):

Use this-:

```
getExternalFilesDir(), getExternalCacheDir(), or getExternalMediaDir() (methods on Context) instead of Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
```

Comment: using this methods,  file  are unistalled after app unistalled... useless